# Is there something like an equivalent of a "Go get Flash" link for HTML5?

Tags: html

I'm building a website that requires HTML5 features in order to run.  If the features are not present in the browser we display a message to the user that they need to upgrade their browser in order to fully view the content.

What I would like to do is provide a link to a site with some information on what HTML5 is and what browsers support it, etc.

We'd prefer not have to build out our HTML5 information pages and just link to something "official" instead.  Similar to the "Go get Flash" link (to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) that is usually used to direct the user to Adobe if Flash isn't present.

Does such a site exist?

Comment: **Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ**. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope.

Comment: Your only target audience is almost definitely IE8 and below. Other browsers typically upgrade themselves (and don't require OS updates to do so), and have already supported HTML5 for a long time. In that case, this is the usual "upgrade your browser" routine for IE then isn't it, nothing specific to HTML5? Agree? I mean, a user can't *install* HTML5, they can only use another browser that supports it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the API from [html5please.com](http://html5please.com) . It will show a message if the HTML5 features your site requires are unavailable on the user's browser and give them links to where they can download a browser that supports those features.

The message is configurable, but can look like this:
[image]

**http://api.html5please.com/**

These are some websites that may help explain the need to upgrade your browser:

- http://browsehappy.com/
- http://www.updatebrowser.net/
- http://www.whatbrowser.org/en/
- http://upgradeyourbrowser.net/